# WordPress only showing home page after migration

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm currently working on a WordPress website. I have taken a database dump from my site and imported to localhost. When I open the localhost, only home page is working, all the other pages are showing error:

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You need to update your URL's within the database as they'll still be reading the localhost URL.

Comment: go to the admin, setting--- permalink setting , change the permalink to default and save, again set the permalink to your custom and save , then check the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need change all permalinks in database. For example use [wp-cli](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206370/126043).
Open cmd (windows) in your WordPress folder, and execute this command

```
wp search-replace "http://old-url.website" "http://new-url.website" --all-tables
```

or use this tool [link](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). This tool special for wordpress.